# Passing parameters from frontend to be used in backend

Tags: javascript, express, axios, cors, fetch-api

I have a frontend (html) and Node.js backend (express). I want to make a request to a 3rd party api but having cors issues.

Now I want to be able to grab the value of an input and append it to my backend url upon request on frontend (e.g `localbackend:3000/${input_value}`), then use the passed parameter (`input_value`) in my backend to form the api url that I need to make a call to the external api.

A bit of code:

index.html

```
<input type="text" id="text">
```

index.js

```
document.getElementById("send").addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  var message = document.getElementById("text").value;

  if (message == undefined || message == "") {
  } else {
    let response = "";

    await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/${message}`)
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((data) => response = data)
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));

.... then response to be appended to another div...
```

server.js

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
axios
    .request(
      `http://someexternalserver/get?uid="simon"&msg=${where_i_need_the_input}` 
    )
    .then(function (response) {
      res.send(JSON.stringify(response.data));  
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error(error);
    });
});
```

Manually I am able to successfully test the external api but I want this done dynamically.

Feel free to share a better solution or simply how to get this working. No FE frameworks please.

I tried:

Rob's cors-anywhere (`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/`) proxy which the api has restricted.

Comment: "I'm having a CORS issue"--what issue? With what request?

Comment: Hi @DaveNewton, ideally i want to simply fetch the api on the frontend but i get the classic `Access to fetch at 'http://api.someserver/get?simon%22&msg=fsdsaf' from origin 'http://localhost:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` I tried to add the headers but still get the same error. If i could get the data i need on the frontend, i don't need a backend.

Comment: You can't add the headers to somebody *else's* web app; that'd defeat the purpose.